# Using Dynamic Data Display (D3) to Generate Graph with Multiple Y Axes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, plot, dynamic-data-display

I have read so much material and tried so many things over the past week and I am not getting anywhere with this.

I have a main window `MainWindowView` which has checkboxes as defined below:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ocv_checkbox, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2" Content="OCV"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=battery_temperature_checkbox, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2" Content="Battery Temperture"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=slope_checkbox, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0, 0, 0, 2" Content="Slope"/>
```

Depending on which boxes are checked, I want to plot a line on a graph when the user clicks a `Button`. **I want all lines on the *same* graph.**

The issue is that depending on the box clicked I may need an additional axis to plot on. For example, if I have 3 checkboxes 1 2 and 3. Number 1 and 2 have units of inches and checkbox 3 has units of gallons. If all 3 are checked, I will need a vertical axis for inches on the left (or right) side and an axis for gallons of the right side (to plot 3).

How do I do that programatically using D3? There is not much documentation at all and I have need seen a clear answer online.

Currently I have:

```
<d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter" Margin="10,10,20,10">
    <d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
        <d3:HorizontalIntegerAxis Name="dateAxis"/>
    </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
    <d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>
        <d3:VerticalIntegerAxis Name="countAxis"/>
    </d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>

    <d3:Header FontFamily="Arial" Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisGraphWindowInstance, Path=title}"/>
    <d3:VerticalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial" Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisGraphWindowInstance, Path=yAxis}"/>
    <d3:HorizontalAxisTitle FontFamily="Arial" Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisGraphWindowInstance, Path=xAxis}"/>
</d3:ChartPlotter>
```

in my `GraphWindowView.xaml` which obviously only has 2 axes. I would like to add one using the code behind if possible.

Thank you,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple Y axis, go for the **InjectedPlotter** object. Foreach type of data (inch, gallons...), you will need an InjectedPlotter that you add as a **children** to your **chartplotter**. When all the lines of one kind of data are disabled (checkboxes unchecked), just hide the injected plotter. You have to link each lines with his correct axis (injected plotter).